# Traverse a directory and its sub directories in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How to traverse a directory and its sub directories in Inno Setup Pascal scripting? I can not find any method and interface in Inno Setup Help Document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`FindFirst`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_findfirst) and [`FindNext`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_findnext) support functions.

```pascal
procedure RecurseDirectory(Path: string);
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  FilePath: string;
begin
  if FindFirst(Path + '\*', FindRec) then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        if (FindRec.Name <> '.') and (FindRec.Name <> '..') then
        begin
          FilePath := Path + '\' + FindRec.Name;
          if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0 then
          begin
            Log(Format('File %s', [FilePath]));
          end
            else
          begin
            Log(Format('Directory %s', [FilePath]));
            RecurseDirectory(FilePath);
          end;
        end;
      until not FindNext(FindRec);
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('Failed to list %s', [Path]));
  end;
end;
```

---

For examples of use, see:

- [Copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Inno Setup Code section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391915/850848)
- [Search subdirectories for Inno Setup DestDir](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34126214/850848)
- [Check if file exists anywhere in C: drive in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37133947/850848)
- [Inno Setup get directory size including subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41668433/850848)