# How can I check SQLCMD.EXE if it is installed on client in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, sqlcmd

I am writing a script for Inno Setup installer and I want my script to check if the client has the tool `SQLCMD.EXE` or not.

I do not know how to do that, is there any script to check for example the registry and tell the client it is not installed ; the msgBox *'Do you want to install them from Microsoft Site?'*

I found this but does not work

```pascal
if RegQueryStringValue(
  HKLM, 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn'.
```

- MySQL Version is 2014 &
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    12.0.2000.8

I found it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36433

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqlcmd.exe` path is put into the search path (`PATH`) by the SQL server installer. [You yourself rely on this in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39721179/850848).

So, just search for the `sqlcmd.exe` in the `PATH`:

```pascal
if FileSearch('sqlcmd.exe', GetEnv('PATH')) = '' then
begin
  if MsgBox('Install SQL server?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then
  begin
    // Install here
  end;
end;
```