# How to verify if program is installed in system with Inno Setup Pascal Script?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to verify if user has Docker installed in their system.
If it is installed proceed further otherwise display an error message.

Previously I was looking at the registry group in Windows but it's not the correct way.
I want to check if cmd gives correct output for command `docker`.

```pascal
function GetHKLM: Integer;
begin
  if IsWin64 then
    Result := HKLM64
  else
    Result := HKLM32;
end;

function GetHKU: Integer;
begin
  if IsWin64 then
    Result := HKCU64
  else
    Result := HKCU32;
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  // Opening the setup installer initially
  Result := True;
  //if the docker is present in the machine registry return True else checking user registry
  if not RegKeyExists(GetHKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Docker Inc.') then
  begin
    if not RegKeyExists(GetHKU, 'Software\Docker Inc.') then
    begin   
      // return False to prevent installation to continue 
      Result := False;
      // Display that you need to install docker.
      SuppressibleMsgBox('<Docker not found!>', mbCriticalError, MB_OK, IDOK);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

How do I do this with just cmd? Instead of checking registry.. How can I run the command line and verify the output?

for etc:

```pascal
function checkdocker() :Boolean;
var
  dockerfound: string;
begin
  Result :=    
    ShellExecute(application.handle, 'docker', nil, nil, SW_MAXIMIZE)
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if not checkdocker then;
    SuppressibleMsgBox('<Docker not found!>', mbCriticalError, MB_OK, IDOK);
  else
    #continue
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your literal question: Just use [`Exec`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) and check the result code:

```pascal
function CheckDocker: Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Result :=
    Exec('docker', '', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) and
    (ResultCode = 0);

  if Result then Log('Succeeded executing docker')
    else Log('Failed to execute docker');
end;
```

*(based on [How to get an output of an Exec'ed program in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1136770/850848))*

---

Though there's more efficient way to check if `docker.exe` executable is in a search path. Use [`FileSearch`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filesearch). See [How can I check SQLCMD.EXE if it is installed on client in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39727672/850848).